# How to switch from 32-bit to PAE paging directly?

Tags: assembly, x86, paging, osdev, page-tables

I'm developing a microkernel for my personal research. I have chosen to run my kernel at `0xf0000000`, leaving 3.75 GiB for user space programs. When my kernel starts up, it sets up 32-bit paging (with hardcoded page directory and page tables). Then it checks if PAE is supported on host machine and sets up page directory pointer table (PDPT). But the problem comes when I try to load it into `%cr3`. According to the Intel Software Developer Manual:

> Software can transition between 32-bit paging and PAE paging by changing the value of CR4.PAE with MOV to CR4.

So tried to use the following code to switch to PAE paging:

```
movl %cr4, %eax
orl $(1 << 5), %eax
movl %eax, %cr4
movl %ebx, %cr3 // %ebx holds physical address to PDPT
```

Or, in Intel syntax (or NASM):

```
mov eax, cr4
or eax, 1 << 5
mov cr4, eax
mov cr3, ebx // ebx holds physical address to PDPT
```

But it fails (on QEMU). It writes to `%cr4`, sets `%eip` to next instruction, executes it (atleast GDB says this), and resets. I tried to write to `%cr3` before `%cr4`, but still the same result.

Then I tried to switch to PAE paging by: unset PG -> set PAE -> write to `%cr3` -> set PG and I succeeded. But I want switch to PAE paging directly. How is that possible?

Comment: Presumably code-fetch fails when CR3 is still pointing to a page table using the legacy 32-bit format.   Does your emulator show you the triple-fault reason?  If not, use BOCHS.  I wonder if a real CPU might let this happen to work (with a TLB hit in an existing translation), unless toggling PAE flushes TLB entries.  With interrupts disabled, it might even be somewhat safe (in practice if not on paper), if those instructions are in the same page.  Although in a VM, there are many more ways a TLB entry could be evicted at any time.

Comment: I don't suppose you can craft a top-level page directory that points at a valid legacy-32-bit PTE if interpreted one way, and a valid PAE 2nd level if interpreted that way?  That might be what you need in CR3 if I'm guessing right.  (Maybe with an EIP with its high bits chosen so that it will select different entries in the top-level table, so you can have two different formats.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: That should work in theory - e.g. if code is at 8 MiB then it'd be using page directory entry at "offset 8 in page at CR3" for plain paging, and PDPT entry at "offset 0 in page at CR3" with PAE. I'd be willing to bet that original asker is using identity mapped code at a lower address though (would have to redesign way too much for something that's likely to have "undiscovered errata").

Comment: @Brendan I'm not using identity mapping. I'm loading  my paging structure in two-stage. First I map first 16 MiB of memory to ``0x0`` and ``0xf0000000`` in the ``_start`` function. Then I jump to higher half and check if PAE is available. Then I generate the appropriate structure where the lower half is unmapped and load it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Then I tried to switch to PAE paging by: unset PG -> set PAE -> write to %cr3 -> set PG and I succeeded. But I want switch to PAE paging directly. How is that possible?

It's not possible.

If "plain paging" is already in use/enabled, then you can't atomically enable PAE and load CR3 at the same time, so (regardless of whether you load CR3 first then CR4, or load CR4 first then try to load CR3) whichever instruction happens first will make the CPU crash before the second instruction is fetched.

The only way is to temporarily disable paging.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I have figured out an way to switch to PAE paging directly, thanks to [@Brendan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559737/brendan) and his [valuable comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67484310/how-to-switch-from-32-bit-to-pae-paging-directly#comment119280780_67484310). To switch to from 32-bit paging to PAE paging directly, I had to trick the CPU. My kernel's virtual base is at `0xf0000000`. So first 960 PDEs were unused after I had jumped to jump higher half. So, I copied my new PDPT (Page Directory Pointer Table) to my initial 32-bit page directory. Then I set PAE bit and the CPU was happy as it was reading only first 32 bytes of the initial page directory which was holding the PDPT.

The process was like this:

1. `memcpy (initial_page_directory, new_pdpt, 32);`
2. Enable PAE bit in `%cr4`. CPU happily reads the PDPT from the first 32 bytes of your initial page directory you have overwritten in step 1.
3. Load your new PDPT into `%cr3`.

**Note: This process won't work if you try to access first 32 MiB of mapped memory (if you have mapped it) between step 1 and 2 (possibly undefined behaviour or maybe a triple fault and reset).**

Comment: Do you think this will work on every version of intel cpu you encounter?  It sounds like you are in a `happens to work on this implementation` area.  Secondly, have you tried it inside of a virtual machine?  I ask that because you might get away with this because any inherent inconsistency might be masked by the quick transition; whereas your sequence will cause several vmexits, which may not be so happy with your hybrid model.   It really isn't difficult to write a position independent blurb to do it by the book, copy it to unity mapped memory, and jump to it.

Comment: Will the processor access the PDEs that I never access, @mevets?

Comment: It may.  It does speculatively execute, and doing so can disrupt the page caches.  Intel leave much of this unspecified, so discovered behaviour may not be very reliable.

Comment: You may be able to prevent speculative access with an MTRR setting of uncacheable or WC.  Possibly even in the PAT flags in the page table or page directory entries, if that works.