# How do I use PAE in x86 protected mode?

Tags: x86, protected-mode, memory-access

How do I use the extra memory given by the Physical Address Extension? Is it like paging where there are table entries? or does it use segment registers? how do I access that extended memory?

Comment: Did you already check [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67484310)? As far as I understand (this is a bit outside my core expertise), you just need to set `CR4.PAE` (bit 5 of the `CR4` register) to 1 in order to enable PAE. [The OSDev Wiki](https://wiki.osdev.org/Setting_Up_Paging_With_PAE) is generally a reliable resource, too.

Comment: I forgot control registers existed, thank you for the reply.

Comment: You have to juggle page-table entries; virtual address space is still limited to 4GiB, regardless of what you do with segmentation.  PAE kinda sucks for a lot of things, as Linus Torvalds explains: https://cl4ssic4l.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/linus-torvalds-about-pae/